# Votingapi and vote up/down question

Tags: drupal

I have some nodes with a widget vote up/down. I can't understand how can i get integer votes value for various actions without sql requery. For example to hide nodes with rating < 10.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what module you use,(Rate, Fivestar or anything else), all the data stored in Voting API module.
Using [Rules module](http://drup0al.org/project/rules) and VotingAPI Rules integration module you can check values of votes and take arbitrary(but possible) actions.
You may need to add new triggered rule on even "user votes on content" and check if the vote's value is < 10.
Voting API keeps data as a percentage so < 10 means < 10%. Vote count, value of each vote and percentage available as data.

Comment: Yeah that's the solution. But not exactly that i need. I'll try to explane.I have nodes. There are several fields: title, main text, rating(votes value),autor and others. I want to hide main text  under css spoiler if votes value is negative. I make custom node.tpl, but i don't know how to get a votes value from votingapi function(becouse it's already there) without new sql query.